# Squid не кеширует

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

Не могу понять, кеширует ли squid.
В конфиге прописал что бы кешировался только один сайт:

```
acl site dstdomain sitename.com
cache allow site
cache deny all
```

В директории кеша `/var/spool/squid` постоянно 17мб, и не изменяется, хотя лимит в 10гиг.

Прокси работает.

Comment: вот конфиг : (убрал кеширование только одного сайта)

Comment: вот [конфиг](http://prntscr.com/gbp8a5) (вернее скрин, прошу прощение впервые задаю вопрос тут, не получается вставить текст конфига)

Comment: Захожу на удаленный компьютер, прописываю параметры прокси в браузере, проверяю IP - он меняется на ip прокси, но кеширование не работает ( я так думаю) ибо как была папка с кешем 17 мб так и осталась 17 мб